# Apply Changes for <div> using a javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my div class.

```
<div class="panel-body relative" ng-attr-id="{{{{$parent.p.cameraId}}}}"></div>
```

How to replace the "string" of below codes with above ng-attr-id?

```
var target = document.getElementById('string');
```

Comment: Hey you have mixed up.In angular there is interpolation this is not the way you do it.If you want to do like wise please use value attribute and bind the string value there.This is totally wrong If you use angular you should do it the angular way and try to avoid jQuery.

Comment: @Tharuka,are you wanted to set the id dynamically? or you need to set the id of returned ID attribute

Comment: @KishorVelayutham Yes, I want to set the id dynamically. I want to make changes for the div based on the cameraId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do some code modification

```
<div class="panel-body relative" id='string' ng-attr-id="{{{{$parent.p.cameraId}}}}"></div>

id='string'


var target = document.getElementById('string').getAttribute('ng-attr-id');
```

Comment: with <div class="panel-body relative" id='string' ng-attr-id="{{$parent.p.cameraId}}"></div> I was able to create a div with the cameraId.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

```
<div class="panel-body relative" ng-attr-id="{{$parent.p.cameraId}}"></div>
```

The value comes from your scope! and gets interpolated. You can't change the view when its already rendered. Because the output of your code will be something like:

```
<div class="panel-body relative" id="foo"></div>
```

So that attribute is not there anymore. You have to change your parent scope value. The parent you should be able to reach with a service or so. If you are new with developing and starting with AngularJS personally i would skip that ancient thing and move to Angular.

From your question i see that you want to change things according to the cameraId but then you should simply use views and not mix vanilla JavaScript with Angular.

Comment: but that value is from a parent controller. I'm newbie can you explain more? @Maapteh